# Add div class conditionally and dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am adding a div dynamically using jQuery like so:

```
$('#content').append('<div class="tiles color m-b-10">some text</div>');
```

I would like the class value "color" to be replaced by "green" if x > 0, "red" otherwise

I have tried the following (in variations, no quotes, single and double quotes, etc) but nothing seems to work.

```
$('#content').append('<div class="tiles'+ x > 0 ? "green" : "red"+ ' m-b-10">some text</div>');`enter code here`
```

My question is a) is it feasible? b) if yes, how?

Comment: what is the html? I think it's different with the idea you explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this this will works

```
$('#content').append('<div class="tiles '+ (x > 0 ? "green" : "red")+ ' m-b-10">some text</div>');
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, i tried everything before except the parentheses (even tried curly brackets)

thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = 5;
  var color = x > 0 ? 'green' : 'red'; // Preprocess the class first 
  $('#content').append('<div class="tiles ' + color + ' m-b-10"></div>'); 
  
  x = -1;
  var color = x > 0 ? 'green' : 'red'; // Preprocess the class first 
  $('#content').append('<div class="tiles ' + color + ' m-b-10"></div>'); 
  
  // For one liner solution
  x = 10;
  $('#content').append('<div class="tiles ' + ( x > 0 ? 'green' : 'red') + ' m-b-10"></div>'); 
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
}
.green{
   background-color: green; 
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: this worked too, but i was opting for a one liner, like ubm's solution below. thanks

Comment: @Panikos I can modify it, I just considered readability of my codes